# Favorite questions and answers from the first quarter of 2014

Tags: discussion, blog

Please link to your favorite questions and answers which were either asked or answered from January 1st 2014 through March 31st 2014.

Your answers will be compiled into a blog post like previous [quarterly posts](http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/2014/01/highlights-from-2013-4th-quarter/).

I will be using DavRob60's queries for a baseline, but I really appreciate people voicing the ones they really enjoyed. Maybe you feel like you answered one really well, even if it didn't receive a lot of votes. Let me know about it.

- [Questions with most **Votes** created within 3 month range](http://data.stackexchange.com/science%20fiction%20and%20fantasy/query/106579/questions-with-most-votes-created-within-3-month-range?StartDate=2013/07/01)
- [Questions with most **View** created within 3 month range](http://data.stackexchange.com/science%20fiction%20and%20fantasy/query/106705/questions-with-most-view-created-within-3-month-range?StartDate=2013/07/01)
- [Questions with **best answer** created within 3 month range](http://data.stackexchange.com/science%20fiction%20and%20fantasy/query/106709/questions-with-best-answer-created-within-3-month-range?StartDate=2013/07/01)

Comment: I have to award myself "most dreadful pun" for this quarter: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/48945/do-lord-of-the-rings-or-the-silmarillion-pass-the-bechdel-test/48950#48950

Answer (score 1):

I enjoyed several questions on Middle Earth, especially non-trivial ones that address how a society would develop, and answers that quote Tolkien's surprisingly extensive correspondence on the subject.

- [How well-known is the theology of Middle-earth, in Middle-earth?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/48262/how-well-known-is-the-theology-of-middle-earth-in-middle-earth)
- [Why did Sauron keep Mount Doom alive after forging of the One Ring?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/48641/why-did-sauron-keep-mount-doom-alive-after-forging-of-the-one-ring)

I also enjoyed this question (And @Slytherincess's answer), both for its content and for the dynamics of VtC->Clarification->Acceptance

- [Is there any evidence supporting or contradicting the theory that Harry is an abused child, imagining it all?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/48747/is-there-any-evidence-supporting-or-contradicting-the-theory-that-harry-is-an-ab)

Answer (score 0):

I felt like this was a good question and that my answer was nicely comprehensive;

[What is the meaning of the way that Kirk's clothes are?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/47050/what-is-the-meaning-of-the-way-that-kirks-clothes-are/47053#47053)

Answer (score 0):

I really liked this question:

[Elder wand: age or wood?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/51445/elder-wand-age-or-wood)

Admittedly I might be a little biased because I got a lot of votes for my answer to it as well, but it's something I think a lot of people who read the books wouldn't have necessarily been clear on, and not just limited to those whose first language isn't English.